# Extracting body of emails from OUTLOOK to EXCEL

Tags: excel, outlook

As the title says i have many emails in a folder from which i would like to extract them to excel in order to see the data from the emails without reading them all.
The emails are all written with the same type of topics and the only variable is the text like this

Email 1

Topic 1 xxxx
topic 2 cccc
Topic 3 vvvv

Email 2

Topic 1 gggg
topic 2 jjjj
Topic 3 zzzz

I'm dont have permission to use any thir party app because the email wont allow it (company email) its it possible to do it?
Sorry for any stupid questions or lack of information that i can provide without any problem. thanks all

Im expecting to be able to have an excel where i can see all the information by topics

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/30228248/4961700

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/27673002/4961700